# URL Rewrite gets rewritten with Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, iis, nuxt.js

I have 2 domains that is mapped to a single NuxtJS STatic Generated app. domain1.com should be just normal. But I want domain2.com to only show domain1.com/chat/ page on its every single URL may it be homepage or /h/ and /n/.

I already put a URL Rewrite on the desired folder location like /chat/. When I vist domain2.com the URL rewrite takes effect and renders the /chat/index.html, but immediately after the rewrite takes effect the router will also take effect then brings me to the homepage.

Is there a way to solve this? I am using IIS URL Rewrite in a Microsoft 2012 server by the way

Comment: According to my understanding, you want the page of domain1.com/chat/ to be displayed when the url is domain2.com, and the page is homepage. Since the rewrite takes effect and brought you to the homepage, isn't this correct? If I have any misunderstanding, can you tell me the original url and rewritten url?

Comment: Correct, the page is homepage but should display the chat page

Comment: Sorry, I 'm still confused about your need. Can you give me some sample url to explain it?